# Thymeleaf: processing inner elements

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my current spring-boot project, I have the follow thymeleaf processor:

```
public class Form extends AbstractProcessor {
  public static Element form = new Element("form");

  @Override
  public ProcessorResult doProcess(Arguments arguments,ProcessorMatchingContext context,Node node) {
    form.setProcessable(true);
    form.setAttribute("role", "form");
    form.setAttribute("class", "form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    node.getParent().insertBefore(node, form);

    List<Element> lista = node.getParent().getElementChildren();
    for(Element child : lista) {
      if(!child.getOriginalName().equals("form")) {
        child.moveAllChildren(form);
      }
    }

    node.getParent().removeChild(node);
    return ProcessorResult.OK;
  }

  @Override
  public int getPrecedence() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public IProcessorMatcher<? extends Node> getMatcher() {
    return new ElementNameProcessorMatcher("form");
  }
}
```

which handles this tag:

```
  <form:form>
    <field-box th:each="item : ${command.getClass().getDeclaredFields()}">
      <div th:each="item2 : ${item.getDeclaredAnnotations()}">
        <div th:switch="${item2.annotationType().getSimpleName()}">
          <div th:case="'Checkbox'"><field:checkbox/></div>
          <div th:case="'DataList'"><field:datalist/></div>
          <div th:case="'Input'"><field:input/></div>
          <div th:case="'Radiobutton'"><field:radio/></div>
          <div th:case="'Select'"><field:select/></div>
          <div th:case="'Textarea'"><field:textarea/></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </field-box>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cadastrar</button>

    <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <span class="text">Configura&ccedil;&atilde;o salva com sucesso</span>
    </div>

    <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <span class="text"></span>
    </div>
  </form:form>
```

and generate this output:

```
 <form role="form" class="form" action="" method="post">
    <field-box th:each="item : ${command.getClass().getDeclaredFields()}">
      <div th:each="item2 : ${item.getDeclaredAnnotations()}">
        <div th:switch="${item2.annotationType().getSimpleName()}">
          <div th:case="'Checkbox'"><field:checkbox></field:checkbox></div>
          <div th:case="'DataList'"><field:datalist></field:datalist></div>
          <div th:case="'Input'"><field:input></field:input></div>
          <div th:case="'Radiobutton'"><field:radio></field:radio></div>
          <div th:case="'Select'"><field:select></field:select></div>
          <div th:case="'Textarea'"><field:textarea></field:textarea></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </field-box>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cadastrar</button>

    <div id="yes" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <span class="text">Configura&ccedil;&atilde;o salva com sucesso</span>
    </div>

    <div id="not" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
      <span class="text"></span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

as seen in the example above, the code it's not processing the elements inside the tag `<form:form>`. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for this issue. The final code for the processor class FormProcessor is that:

```
public class Form extends AbstractProcessor {
  public static Element form = new Element("form");

  @Override
  public ProcessorResult doProcess(Arguments arguments,ProcessorMatchingContext context,Node node) {
    form.setProcessable(true);
    form.setAttribute("role", "form");
    form.setAttribute("class", "form");
    form.setAttribute("action", "");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    node.getParent().insertBefore(node, form);

    List<Element> lista = node.getParent().getElementChildren();
    for(Element child : lista) {
      if(!child.getOriginalName().equals("form")) child.moveAllChildren(form);
    }

    List<Element> lista2 = form.getElementChildren();
    for(Element child : lista2) {
      child.setProcessable(true);
    }

    node.getParent().removeChild(node);
    return ProcessorResult.OK;
  }

  @Override
  public int getPrecedence() {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public IProcessorMatcher<? extends Node> getMatcher() {
    return new ElementNameProcessorMatcher("form");
  }
}
```